# Power Shell: A command as a variable with parameter

Tags: powershell, parameters, command

I have a simple question. I would like to assign a command to a variable and execute it with extra parameters, like:

```
C:\test.exe /q /v
```

But when I do:

```
$path=C:\test.exe
$path /q /v
```

It doesn't work.. Any idea?

Comment: Can you say what the error is and how do expect it to work?

Comment: It's a syntax error, or my command is launched without parameters, so when I run $path /q /v, PS runs $path instead.

Answer (score 3):

The most canonical way to do this is to use the call operator on the variable that contains the "name" of the command e.g.:

```
& $path /q /v
```

This is actually required when the path to the command (ie native exe) contains spaces.

Comment: This is the best way, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

**Command as string:**

With Invoke-Expression cmdlet you execute an arbitrary **string** as a piece of code. It takes the string, compiles it, and executes it.

So you do:

```
$path='C:\test.exe';
Invoke-Expression "$path /q /v";
```

*As a side note:* When you do `$path=C:\test.exe` without the quotes, you are actually assigning the STDOUT of `test.exe` to the variable `$path`. You have to make clear to PowerShell that it is actually a string you wish to execute later.

---

**Command as script object:**

If you are concerned with performance, you could also try converting your command to a compiled scriptblock, and execute it with the `&` call operator.

```
$path='C:\test.exe';
$cmd = [scriptblock]::Create("$path /q /v");
& $cmd;
```